# How to change all my textbox input letters to uppercase in mvc razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

**Heres my TextBox**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name"} })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js:

```
$(function () {
        $("input").each(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        })
    })
```

It will change all the inputs' values to uppercase when page loaded.If you want to change all my textbox input letters to uppercase when input lose focus,you can use:

```
 $("input").change(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    })
```